Deriving the expectation of a sum of a random number of i.i.d random variables; why use conditioning?
If we have a non-negative-integer valued discrete random variable $N$, as well as independent and identically-distributed random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ (where $N \perp X_i$ as well), consider the sum
$$
S = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} X_i
$$
If we wanted to find the expectation $\textbf{E}\left[S\right]$, the approach I have seen used is to condition on the particular value of $N$, which is what is done in this question, for example.
However, my question is, doesn't the following simpler derivation suffice?
$$
\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}\left[S\right] &= \textbf{E}\left[\sum_{i = 1}^{N} X_i\right]\\
&= \textbf{E}\left[N \cdot X_i\right] && \text{Because all $X_i$ are i.i.d.}\\
&= \textbf{E}\left[N\right] \cdot \textbf{E}\left[X_i\right] && \text{Because expectation is multiplicative across independent r.v's}
\end{align*}
$$This gives us the correct answer, but doesn't require us to condition on the value of $N$; it instead just applies the fact that expectation is multiplicative across independent random variables. Is this approach incorrect? If not, is there a reason why we wouldn't use this approach over conditioning?

I think maybe your way assumes that $N$ and $X_1$ are independent which is different from just saying the $X_i$ are iid??

@SBK Sorry, I forgot to say that we assume $N$ is independent of all $X_i$.

Oh wait I’m being stupid, the error is much clearer: You can’t replace the sum inside the expectation with $NX_i$ (or $NX_1$, which is what you probably mean). That would be like saying all the $X_i$ have literally the same value almost everywhere.

@SBK Oh, I think I see! So I can't replace $\sum_{i = 1}^N X_i$ with $N \cdot X_i$, because that assumes all $X_i$ take on the same value, which may not be true. All we're given is that all $X_i$ have the same distribution (so $\textbf{E}\left[X_i\right]$ is identical for all $i$), but that in no way implies that all the values of $X_i$ are equal.

What makes it hard to judge is the fact that the equalities you mention are all valid. This because in all cases both sides start with the expectation symbol. If I would meet this somewhere I would think things like: "...mmm, this guy might be taking the liberty to skip some steps".

Yes, the expectations of $\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ and $N X_1$ are the same but those random variables do not share the same distribution so you can't make the logical jump you want to do.  For example, if $N\sim Poisson(10)$ and $X_i \sim N(0,1)$, then $N X_1$ has 10 times the variance of $\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$.

Your "simpler derivation" isn't really simpler to someone like me for which the identity $\ \mathbf{E}\left[\sum_\limits{i=1}^NX_i\right]=\mathbf{E}\big[N\cdot X_i\big]\ $ isn't at all obvious. While the identity does in fact hold when $\ N\ $ is independent of all the $\ X_i\ ,$ it doesn't necessarily do so if that condition isn't satisfied.  So to be convinced that the identity holds when $\ N\ $ is independent of all the $\ X_i\ $ I'd need to see an argument containing a step that uses the independence condition itself, or a well known consequence of it, but which could fail when the independence condition does not hold.  Nevertheless, it's certainly not necessary that such an argument  must expand out the identity $\ \mathbf{E}[S]=$$\,\mathbf{E}[\mathbf{E}[S|N]]\ $ in terms of $\ \mathbf{E}[S|N=n]\ .$ Here's one that doesn't. It expands $\ S\ $ out in terms of the indicator random variables $\ \mathbb{I}_{\{N=n\}}\ $ instead.
\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^NX_i\right]&=\mathbf{E}\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbb{I}_{\{N=n\}}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right]\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbf{E}\big[\mathbb{I}_{\{N=n\}}\big]\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{E}\big[X_i\big]\label{1}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbf{E}\big[\mathbb{I}_{\{N=n\}}\big]n\mathbf{E}\big[X_i\big]\label{2}\tag{2}\\
&=\mathbf{E}\left[X_i\sum_{i=1}^\infty n\mathbb{I}_{\{N=n\}}\right]\tag{3}\label{3}\\
&=\mathbf{E}\big[NX_i\big]
\end{align}
The equations \eqref{1} and \eqref{3} are where the independence condition needs to be invoked in the above argument.
Observe that if your aim is to prove $\ \mathbf{E}\left[\sum_\limits{i=1}^NX_i\right]=$$\,\mathbf{E}[N]\mathbf{E}\big[X_i\big]\ ,$ then after the step \eqref{2} in the above argument you could simply invoke the identity $\ \sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty\mathbf{E}\big[\mathbb{I}_{\{N=n\}}\big]n \mathbf{E}\big[X_i\big]=$$\,\mathbf{E}[N]\mathbf{E}\big[X_i\big]\ $ to establish the conclusion, whereas establishing $\ \mathbf{E}\left[\sum_\limits{i=1}^NX_i\right]=\mathbf{E}\big[NX_i\big]\ $ first and then invoking the identity $\ \mathbf{E}\big[NX_i\big]=\mathbf{E}[N]\mathbf{E}\big[X_i\big]\ $ to reach the conclusion takes two more steps than would otherwise be needed.
